# Coolant in engine... Head gasket going

Tags: coolant, cooling-system, head-gasket, equinox

I have an 05 Equinox, and while idling it sometimes overheats. We have to continously add coolant every week.

If this was the only problem, I'd fix it, but, there's other issues as well, and combined cost of repair is about $3000 (which it is not worth, esp at 150k miles / 250 k km). I'm wondering how long it will take before the Engine goes.  As well, is there anything I can do in the meantime to extend the life of this  vehicle in the meantime?

Comment: Any more info you can add?  You're title states, "coolant in engine".  Can you elaborate?  Is this coolant in your oil and it looks like a milkshake?

Comment: I had the exhaust fumes tested at a mechanic and he said there was coolant in the exhaust, which meant that the coolant was leaking into the engine.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a confirmation that the head gasket is going bad. There is a product that states that it has the capability to fix head gasket leaks, you can give that a try(I have never used it personally). It is called Steel Seal, there are a lot of videos on the You tube about how to use this product, give it a try and write a followup review so we too will know about it. I am pretty sure that this not going to be a permanent fix but might push the head gasket replacement a little further.

Good luck.

Comment: If used correctly, this can fix a small coolant leak. If the head is warped or some such which is eating a lot of coolant, this may slow it down, but it isn't going to fix it long term. Good call kasey.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Didn't even know such a product existed! I live in Canada so I'm going to try this: http://www.canadiantire.ca/en/pdp/rislone-head-gasket-fix-0380847p.html Do you  think that'll be ok? Seems to be reviewed well...

Comment: Yeah the reviews look good, give that a try and keep us posted, and make sure you follow all the instructions.

Answer (score 2):

You can fix this yourself with some sockets, a wrench, a torque wrench and probably about 200-500 dollars in work and a few days wait that most machine shops will charge to restore a busted head. You'll need about a hundred bucks to get a new gasket and you'll probably need a good weekend to take all the manifolds, wires, injectors and hoses off the head and label and bag everything appropriately for later reassembly, but it's not rocket science. With practice you can do it in a few hours.

Speaking of which, what shop would charge three grand for a head gasket? Is inflation really that bad? That's like 400-500 dollars in work if I remember right.

Goop and snake oil won't fix a head gasket. Making the surfaces flat, true, clean and uncracked with a fresh gasket is the only thing that works.

Comment: Sorry the $3000 was how much total repairs was required for the vehicle, which was the deciding factor in not extending the life of it.  Plus, Canadian dollars ;).